# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<decimal>' to 'decimal'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

Need help, am new programmer and I want to IEnumerable to a decimal, thanx!! Update stock is a field in OrderdMaterials table

```
 partial void Quantity_Compute(ref decimal result)
    {
        // Set result to the desired field value
        if (OrderdMaterialsCollection != null)
        {
            var myMat = OrderdMaterialsCollection.Select(a => a.UpdatedStock);

            result = myMat;

        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to do some aggregation on your stock values. E.g. .Sum()

Comment: @lazyberezovsky The OP may not want an aggregate, but it does bring up the question. Is the `OrderdMaterialsCollection` intended to be used in aggregate or will there really just be a *first* or *single* record?

Comment: Perhaps you need a number of items with `UpdatedStock==true`?

Comment: @sll The error seems to indicate that `UpdatedStock` is a `decimal` value, bizarre at that name may be.

Answer (score 7):

The `Select()` method returns an `IEnumerable` of `decimal` in your case. Which means that it can be more than one `decimal`. If you just want to have the first or you know that there is only one you can use `First()`. Here you can read more on [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx).

```
/*IEnumerable<decimal>*/ 
var myMat = OrderdMaterialsCollection.Select(a => a.UpdatedStock);

result = myMat.First();
```